# How does SDRs implement anti-aliasing filters, when the sampling rate can be fairly arbitrary?

Tags: sampling, software-defined-radio, anti-aliasing-filter

I was looking at the [schematic](https://files.ettus.com/schematics/b200mini/b200mini.pdf) for the small USRP B205-mini SDR from Ettus. I can't seem to find any switchable analog anti-aliasing filter on the input of the chip, or anything resembling a filter for that matter.

This would mean that the filtering is done inside the chip. But how? When using software like GNU Radio, you can basically choose an arbritary sample rate within the IC's specification. Does the chip have a huge filterbank for filtering the input that is switched in, depending on the sample rate, or how does it eliminate anti-aliasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the front end of the SDR.  The first active component in the schematic is the [AD9364 1 x 1 RF Agile Transceiver](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad9364.html).  This device is where the analog mixing and band limiting filtering, analog-to-digial conversion, and digital channelization occur.

[image]

Quoting from the data sheet:

> The receiver includes 12-bit, Σ-Δ ADCs and adjustable sample rates
> that produce data streams from the received signals. The digitized
> signals can be conditioned further by a series of decimation filters
> and a fully programmable 128-tap FIR filter with additional decimation
> settings. The sample rate of each digital filter block is adjustable
> by changing decimation factors to produce the desired output data
> rate.

The initial band limiting occurs after the mixer. This provide anti-aliasing for the ADC.  Any further decimation and associated anti-aliasing filtering occurs within the reconfigurable digital logic based on the selected decimation factors.

Here is a more detail diagram as suggested by [user67081](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/4794/user67081) ([link](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/ad-fmcomms2-ebz/ad9361) to original).

[image]

A lot more detail can be found at the [Analog Devices Wiki](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/ad-fmcomms2-ebz/ad9361).

Comment: This is a more informative block diagram: https://wiki.analog.com/_media/resources/eval/user-guides/ad-fmcomms2-ebz/ad9361.svg?w=950&h=650&tok=152c99

Basically - the ad9361 has built in reconfigurable analog anti-aliasing filters prior to the ADC. The subsequent digital filters (FIRs + Halfbands) allow the ADC rate to be further decimated - note that there are a lot of constraints e.g. maximum ADC clock rate, PLL constraints, maximum rate through each of the digital filters, etc - but the gist of it is a combination of ADC clock rate + digital FIR configs enables a wide range of samplerates

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basically, the ADC in the RF tranceiver always runs at it highest sample rate(61.44 MSPS), and depending and how the user programs it, it decimate the signal to fit whatever samplerate the user wants on the digital side. Is this correct? And therefore it only needs to have a single anti-aliasing filter, to fit the 56MHz BW, after the mixer?

Comment: I thought the ADC data rate was actually changing, when you programmed different sample rates on the unit.

Comment: @user67081 thanks!  I've added the more detailed digram to the answer.

Comment: @Linkyyy see the (Analog Devices Wiki)[https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/ad-fmcomms2-ebz/ad9361], there's a lot more detail about the functioning of this part there that is more digestible than the data sheet.

Comment: @Linkyyy the ADC runs at a much higher rate than 61.44 MSPS usually and is not fixed but varies depending on what the requested baseband sample rate is. For example when running at the 61.44 MSPS I/Q baseband rate, the ADC may be running in the Hundreds of MHz and those samples are further decimated down by the integrated configurable digital filter path in order to give you the final 61.44 MSPS baseband rate. Note that although the ADC runs at a much faster rate, you can only get access to the decimated max of 61.44 M due to timing constraints on the dig interface & dig filter path.

Comment: If you want to see the exact rates through the chain, I suggest trying ADI's  matlab ad9361 filter wizard where you can specify a sample rate and have it auto configure default settings for the ADC PLL and digital filter path configuration.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Even though they don't go through how the "RF channel bandwidth" filter is implemented, it seems it is still very variable then.